# NumPy Fast Fourier transform (FFT) does not work on sine wave generated in Audacity

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft, audacity

I am trying to use the NumPy library for Python to do some frequency analysis. I have two .wav files that both contain a 440 Hz sine wave. One of them I generated with the NumPy sine function, and the other I generated in Audacity. The FFT works on the Python-generated one, but does nothing on the Audacity one.

Here are links to the two files:

The non-working file: [440_audacity.wav](https://www.dropbox.com/s/beve365bchpzas5/440_audacity.wav?dl=0)

The working file: [440_gen.wav](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpi1dki6h15ibp1/440_gen.wav?dl=0)

This is the code I am using to do the Fourier transform:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wave

infile = "440_gen.wav"
rate, data = wave.read(infile)

data = np.array(data)

data_fft = np.fft.fft(data)
frequencies = np.abs(data_fft)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(data[:800])
plt.title("Original wave: " + infile)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(frequencies)
plt.title("Fourier transform results")

plt.xlim(0, 1000)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I have two 16-bit PCM .wav files, one from Audacity and one created with the NumPy sine function. The NumPy-generated one gives the following (correct) result, with the spike at 440Hz:
[image: FFT on the numpy generated file]

The one I created with Audacity, although the waveform appears identical, does not give any result on the Fourier transform:
[image: FFT on the audacity generated file]

I admit I am at a loss here. The two files should contain in effect the same data. They are encoded the same way, and the wave forms appear identical on the upper graph.

Here is the code used to generate the working file:

```py
import numpy as np
import wave
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from operator import add

freq_one = 440.0
num_samples = 44100
sample_rate = 44100.0
amplitude = 12800

file = "440_gen.wav"

s1 = [np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq_one * x/sample_rate) * amplitude for x in range(num_samples)]

sine_one = np.array(s1)

nframes = num_samples
comptype = "NONE"
compname="not compressed"
nchannels = 1
sampwidth = 2

wav_file = wave.open(file, 'w')
wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, int(sample_rate), nframes, comptype, compname))

for s in sine_one:
    wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int(s)))
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could share ```440_gen.wav```?

Comment: try record with `aplay 440_gen.wav` in the terminal and see if wav file is correct.

Comment: @Ralph I'm working on uploading both files to attach.

Comment: @darkfire613 Thanks. Just the file generated by audacity should do it since you included the code to produce the python generated ```.wav```. Also, it's not true that the "wave forms appear identical on the upper graph". Though their frequencies are the same the amplitudes are not (although this shouldn't matter and I don't think this is the problem)

Comment: @Ralph I have added Dropbox links to both files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since answering this question @Konyukh Fyodorov was able to provide a better and properly justified solution (below).

---

The following worked for me and produced the plots as expected. Unfortunately I cannot piece together quite why this works, but I'm sharing this solution in the hope it may assist someone else to make that leap.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wave

infile = "440_gen.wav"
rate, data = wave.read(infile)

data = np.array(data)

# Use first 44100 datapoints in transform
data_fft = np.fft.fft(data[:44100])
frequencies = np.abs(data_fft)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(data[:800])
plt.title("Original wave: " + infile)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(frequencies)
plt.title("Fourier transform results")

plt.xlim(0, 1000)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works for me as well, using multiple different sample files I had created in Audacity and struggled with before. Is there a reason why limiting the number of samples is necessary?

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad this worked for you! I'm not really sure why it works though; it's been a long time since I've used Fourier transforms and I can't really remember how they work. I'll need to have a think about it.

Comment: “This worked for me” answers that don’t specify what is changed in the code, nor why it works, don’t help anyone learn. This is an answer that patches code but doesn’t add to the Stack Overflow knowledge base.

Comment: @Cris Luengo respectfully, I disagree: not all problems are solved in a linear fashion. Sometimes seeing a fix before understanding _why_ it's a fix can help bridge a knowledge gap and assist learning. I wasn't able to bridge that gap, but shared my patch in the hope that it may help someone else make that leap. You may choose to prioritise "purity over practicality" of a solution, but not everyone does. The utilitarian in me would have been happy to run for the hills with a solution which worked rather than wait 2 years because of my restrictive personal-philosophy (but that's just me)

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain why your code doesn't work. And why it works with `[:44100]`.

First of all, you have different files:

```
440_gen.wav      = 1 sec and 44100  samples (counts)        
440_audacity.wav = 5 sec and 220500 samples (counts)
```

Since for `440_gen.wav` in FFT you use the number of reference points N=44100 and the sample rate 44100, your frequency resolution is 1 Hz (bins are followed in 1 Hz increments).
Therefore, on the graph, each FFT sample corresponds to a delta equal to 1 Hz.
`plt.xlim(0, 1000)` just corresponds to the range 0-1000 Hz.

However, for `440_audacity.wav` in FFT, you use the number of reference points N=220500 and the sample rate 44100. Your frequency resolution is 0.2 Hz (bins follow in 0.2 Hz increments) - on the graph, each FFT sample corresponds to a frequency in 0.2 Hz increments (min-max = +(-) 22500 Hz).
`plt.xlim(0, 1000)` just corresponds to the range 1000x0.2 = 0-200 Hz.
That is why the result is not visible - it does not fall within this range.

`plt.xlim (0, 5000)` will correct your situation and extend the range to 0-1000 Hz.

The solution `[:44100]` that **jwalton** brought in really only forces the FFT to use N = 44100. And this repeats the situation with the calculation for 440_gen.wav

A more correct solution to your problem is to use the `N (Windows Size)` parameter in the code and the `np.fft.fftfreq()` function.

Sample code below.

I also recommend an excellent article https://realpython.com/python-scipy-fft/

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wave

N = 44100 # added

infile = "440_audacity.wav"
rate, data = wave.read(infile)

data = np.array(data)

data_fft = np.fft.fft(data, N)  # added N
frequencies = np.abs(data_fft)
x_freq = np.fft.fftfreq(N, 1/44100)  # added

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(data[:800])
plt.title("Original wave: " + infile)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(x_freq, frequencies)  # added x_freq 
plt.title("Fourier transform results")

plt.xlim(0, 1000)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: By the way, this would work also without cutting the signal to the first second only, setting `N` to whatever the length of the signal is.

Comment: Thank you for saying that, Cris